# Rust: Distinguish several cases in error handling of fs::remove_file

Tags: rust, error-handling, pattern-matching

In Rust, I want to remove a file. [The documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.remove_file.html) tells me that `fs::remove_file` returns an error if the file is a directory, does not exist or the user lacks the permissions for the action.

Now, in my scenario, I would like to distinguish between those three cases. However, my debugger doesn't show me the type of the error and a `println!` results in simply printing the error message.

So, how could I distinguish between those cases?

```
use std::fs;

fn rem(path: &str) {
  let msg = match fs::remove_file(path) {
    Ok(()) => "is fine",
    Err(NotExist) => "does not exist", // TODO: Pattern
    Err(IsDir) => "is a directory", // TODO: Pattern
    Err(_) => "is not yours",
  };  
  println!("The file {}!", msg);
}

fn main() {
  rem("/tmp/this-file-hopefully-not-exists.xyz"); // print "not exist"
  rem("/tmp/this-is-a-directory"); // prints "is a directory"
  rem("/tmp/this-file-belongs-to-root.xyz"); // prints "is not yours"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::fs::remove_file` returns a `std::io::Result<()>`, which is just an alias for `Result<(), std::io::Error>`.

So you can match on this to extract the type of the error message. In particular, you're probably going to want to look at the `.kind()` of the error:

```rust
fn rem(path: &str) {
  use std::io::ErrorKind;

  let message = match std::fs::remove_file(path) {
    Ok(()) => "ok",
    Err(e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::NotFound => "not found",
    Err(e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::IsADirectory => "is a directory",
    Err(e) => "other",
  }
  println!("{message}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, compiling this fails with "variant or associated term not found in `ErrorKind`", pointing to `IsADirectory`. Apparently, this enum value is in *experimental* and I'm using Rust stable ([Documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/enum.ErrorKind.html#variant.IsADirectory)). In my specific case, I can circumvent this issue, if I swap the branches "is a directory" with "permission denied", and use the wildcard for the last branch.

Comment: By the way, is there a reason why you `use std::io::ErrorKind` inside the `rem` function and not at the top of the file? Is it beneficial to reduce the scope of it?

Comment: @Green绿色 Look at the docs for `remove_file` again, they list exactly 3 cases this function can error in. You can match against `ErrorKind::NotFound` and `ErrorKind::PermissionDenied`, since they are stabilised, then just match against `Err(_)` which _must_ correspond to `ErrorKind::IsADirectory` because that's the only one left. The reason it's like this is that `ErrorKind::IsADirectory` is a recent addition which isn't stabilised yet, that error case would have gone under `ErrorKind::Other`, in which case you'd have to match against `Err(_)` anyway.

Comment: @JMAA Yes. That's what I meant by "swap the branches" above. Thanks for the detailed description.

Comment: When I first wrote the code snippet, it had `use std::io::ErrorKind::*`, which would allow you to write `e.kind() == NotFound`, however I changed that for readability. When glob-importing enum variants, personally I like to keep the scope as limited as possible, though for `std::io::ErrorKind`, the location of the `use` statement is more a matter of personal taste